# How to set validation of max word in textformfield in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-textformfield

```
inputFormatters: [
              LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(50),
            ],
```

The above code in TextFormField restricted character length not words.
I want to set validation that this field only allow to adds Max 50 words in flutter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider the following ways.

1. using a TextFormField with a validator.

```
TextFormField(
  validator: (text) {
    if (text.split(' ').length > max_limit) {
      return 'Reached max words';
    }
    return null;
  },
);
```

2. Add a decoration which will show an error if the limit is crossed.

```
TextField(
  controller: _text,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: 'Enter 5 words',
    errorText: _validate ? 'You have entered more than 5 words' : null,
  ),
);
```

On your OnChanged() -> update the _validate variable based on your condition.

Answer (score 1):

I created a formatter for you.
Add this formatter class to your file and use this

> inputFormatters: [
> LengthLimitingWordInputFormatter(50),
> ],

```
class LengthLimitingWordInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
      final int maxWordLength;
      LengthLimitingWordInputFormatter({required this.maxWordLength});
      @override
      TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
        if (newValue.text.split(" ").length <= maxWordLength) {
          return newValue;
        } else {
          return oldValue;
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use inputFormatters property. The following code would limit the textFormField to 42 in length :

```
new TextFormField(
  inputFormatters: [
    new LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(42),
  ],
);
```

I hope, it helps!

Comment: I used the same. Please check my question again

Comment: please check my next answer